# Converting String to Byte Array and vice versa

Tags: c#, encoding

Converting a string to a byte array and then changing back will sometimes wont return the same string:

```
RandomNumberGenerator gen = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] randomBytes = new byte[32];
gen.GetBytes(randomBytes);
```

In some cases (or any kind of encoding other than unicode):

```
randomBytes != Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(randomBytes));
```

I'd like to know how to do this method and get the same result **for sure**.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you _actually_ using `!=` to compare byte arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you are not looking for a text encoding but a serialization format. Text encodings are meant for text. The bytes you are processing are random bytes.

Does Base64 (`Convert.ToBase64String`) work for you?

You could also jam the bytes into chars (`new string(myBytes.Select(b => (char)b).ToArray())`). This will produce unreadable strings that are prone to being mangled by other systems. Likely not the right path.

Comment: `Convert.ToBase64String` returns a string. I need to convert the string to byte[] and back. I'm using the `NetworkStream` class to transmit strings and it requires a byte[].

Comment: @idotalker why use strings at all? You have bytes, you want bytes. Directly send the bytes. If your protocol is text-based, then you probably need to use bas64 to go to a string, then use an encoding such as UTF8 to go to bytes. This will work with random data. Without base64 it will not.

Comment: I think I might've been a little unclear. The example in this post is not the code I'm working with, I wrote it to show that `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(randomBytes))` will sometimes be different from `randomBytes`. I have no desire to work with random data. My input is a string that I need to send with `NetworkStream`. Goes something like this: `input(string) => encryption => Send (NetworkStream)` and then `Recieve (NetworkStream) => decryption => put string to use`. The byte[] is going through fine but since `Encoding` changes it the decryption doesn't work.

Comment: Why can't you operate with bytes entirely? No strings at all. Encryption does not operate on text anyway. It operates on bytes. @idotalker My points do not depend on the data being random. My point is, if you have arbitrary bytes you cannot make text from them using an encoding.

Answer (score 1):

*Arbitrary* byte array does not necessary encodes a **valid** Unicode string (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16 for details), e.g.

```
  byte[] before = new byte[] { 0xA6, 0xDD };
  byte[] after = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(before));

  if (!before.SequenceEqual(after))
    Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
      $"before: {string.Join(" ", before.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")))}",
      $"after:  {string.Join(" ", after.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")))}"));
```

Outcome:

```
before: a6 dd
after:  fd ff
```

If you want to generate these strings you can modify your code into

```
while (true) {
  using (RandomNumberGenerator gen = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider()) {
    byte[] randomBytes = new byte[32];
    gen.GetBytes(randomBytes);

    byte[] after = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(randomBytes));

    if (!randomBytes.SequenceEqual(after)) {
      Console.Write(string.Join(" ", randomBytes) + 
                    Environment.NewLine + 
                    string.Join(" ", after));

      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Possible outcome:

```
166 8 99 175 188 233 240 219 64 143 26 87 157 209 205 219 27 169 239 67 99 170 172 226 254 56 168 168 64 222 178 15
166 8 99 175 188 233 253 255 64 143 26 87 157 209 253 255 27 169 239 67 99 170 172 226 254 56 168 168 253 255 178 15
                     ^
                     Difference
```

Please, note that we should compare arrays with `SequenceEqual`.

If you want to encode an *array*, you can do it with a help of `string.Join`:

```
byte[] array = ...

// Something like "166 8 99 175 188 233 240 219 ... 64 222 178 15"
string encoded = string.Join(" ", array);

byte[] back = encoded
  .Split(' ')
  .Select(item => byte.Parse(item))
  .ToArray();
```